# identifier merge not found

Tags: c++

Merge sort:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin>> arr[i];
    }
    void mergesort(int arr,int n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
void merge(int* l, int* r, int mid, int x,int *arr) {
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<mid&&j<x){
        if(l[i]<r[i]){
            arr[k++]=l[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k++]=r[j++];        
        }
    }
    while(i<mid){
        arr[k++]=l[i++];
    }
    while(j<x){
        arr[k++]=r[j++];
    }
}
void mergesort(int *arr, int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    int mid, x;
    int* l, * r;
    mid = n / 2;
    x = n - mid;
    l = new int[mid];
    r = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        l[i] = arr[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <x; i++) {
        r[i] = arr[i];
    }
    mergesort(l, mid);
    mergesort(r, x);
    merge(l,r,mid,x,arr);
    delete[] l;
    delete[] r;
}
```

Same array is printing itself.

Am i doing something wrong?

It is saying merge: identifier did not found

how can i resolve the problem?

Comment: this : `void mergesort(int arr,int n);` Is a declaration for a function. Why did you put this line in `main`?

Comment: please include the full error in the question

Comment: You say it is printing *and* there is an error message. There is some important information missing in your post. But, you have not called the sort so why your array is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that due to the using directive

```
using namespace std;
```

the compiler can not resolve an ambiguity.

Use qualified name like `::merge`.

For example

```
::merge(l,r,mid,x,arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `main()`, the line `void mergesort(int arr,int n);` is a function declaration (and it doesn't match the actual implementation of your function).  You are merely declaring `mergesort()`, you are not actually calling it.  So you are printing the same array as your input because you are not actually sorting the array at all.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void mergesort(int *arr,int n); // <-- fixed and moved up here!

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin>> arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]; // <-- added so you can see the array before it is modified!
    }
    cout<<endl;
    mergesort(arr,n); // <-- actually call it now!
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]; // <-- now the array is printed out as modified!
    }
    return 0;
}

void merge(int* l, int* r, int mid, int x,int *arr) {
    ...
}

void mergesort(int *arr, int n) {
    ...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/qFw8FJ)

That said, your `mergesort()` function does not sort the array correctly, ie the input `5 4 5 2 1 3` sorts the array as `44444`.  But that is a different issue you should post a new question about separately.